# <function output at 0x> when calling function

Tags: python, function

```
def num(num1, num2):
    def adder(num):
        return (num1 + num2)
    return adder()

num(5, 6)
```

When I type this code in i get the output of < function num..adder at 0x10b83bdd0 >, and I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong. How do I get it to return 11?

Comment: It returns `adder` object. You can call `num(5, 6)(some_int_value)`

Comment: Why do you even *have* that `adder` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`num` returns a function, so you need to call it:

```
num(5, 6)(0) # the number you call it with is irrelevant since you never use num in adder
# 11
```

In this case this approach is kind of useless. This is usually done if you want to define a partial function or a "function factory", for example:

```
def multiplier(multiply_by):
    def inner(n):
        return multiply_by * n
    return inner

multiply_by_2 = multiplier(2)
multiply_by_4 = multiplier(4)

print(multiply_by_2(4))
print(multiply_by_4(4))
```

Outputs

```
8
16
```

Your example would have made more sense if the argument was actually used in the inner function, then this becomes very similar to my example above but using addition instead of multiplication:

```
def adder(num1):
    def inner(num2):
        return num1 + num2
    return inner

two_adder = adder(2)
three_adder = adder(3)

print(two_adder(2))
print(three_adder(2))
```

Outputs

```
4
5
```

Answer (score 0):

You return the adder function, but you don't call it.

Answer (score 0):

The function returns another function. If you want a number, you need to call the returned function as well:

```
f = adder(1, 2)
print(f(4))  # Call the returned f
```

Although the second call is useless since you never make use of `num`.